# Highstock step multiple data points on same x axis

Tags: highcharts

When the highstock chart data set has multiple points on the same axis ex:

```
data:  [[0,0], [0, 100], [1, 100], [1,200], [4, 100], [4, 200]]
```

the point doesn't always choose the highest number by default. It looks like it randomly selects one of the numbers on the same axis.

Here's my fiddler example: http://jsfiddle.net/ceo1y97m/

As you can see when you hover over the different points, it's not always displaying the highest point's Y value. How do I get this to show only the highest point's value?

Edit: Here is the reason that I have multiple x values that are the same:

Let's say the line represents the amount of money you deposit into an account over time. In the line's legend I want to display the amount you've deposited over the period that you're viewing. This would be the furthest point right's Y value minus the furthest point left's Y value. If I don't include the duplicate Y values, this calculation is incorrect.

See updated fiddler to show this error on the legend value (zoom in and out to change the legend values): https://jsfiddle.net/LS384/822/

The two data sets look identical, but the legend values are different, because both points on the same axis aren't displayed.

Comment: Agreed with Liviu Boboia answer. Why do you need those additional points?

Comment: I have an additional requirement to calculate the difference between the furthest right and furthest left point (to see the value's change over time). See my comment on Liviu's post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would process the data, so you have one point per x value with additional information - multiple values. I treat `{ x, y }` as the information about how the point should be visualised plus add the array with all additional values which allow to make the proper calculations.

This:

```
[
  [0, 0],
  [0, 100],
  [1, 100],
  [1, 200],
  [1, 300],
```

becomes this:

```
[{
  x: 0,
  y: 100,
  values: [0, 100]
}, {
  x: 1,
  y: 300,
  values: [100, 200, 300]
}]
```

With points defined as the above, you can access the values via `point.options.values` and calculate the difference.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/jqdh79vv/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that this is how the step chart was intended to be used, you should have just 1 value per axis point.
What you could do is filter your data to just keep the highest value for each point

```
data:  [[0,0], [0, 100], [1, 100], [1,200], [4, 100], [4, 200]]

for (var i in data) {
    if (filteredData[data[i][0]] == undefined) {
        filteredData[data[i][0]] = data[i]
    } else {
       if (filteredData[data[i][0]][1] < data[i][1]) {
       filteredData[data[i][0]] = data[i];
       }
    }
}
```

here is your edited filter with the chart looking the same and you desired behaviour http://jsfiddle.net/ceo1y97m/4/

Edit:

I made a workaround, i hid the unfiltered data, used the filtered data for display and gave it the same color as the unfiltered one, and in the function that calculates the difference i use the unfiltered data(ch.series[0].data])

Here is the fiddle with your expected behaviour https://jsfiddle.net/LS384/826/

Comment: See updated question as to why more than 1 value per axis point is required.